# Conflicting mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the full set of rewrite code in my htaccess file, but I'm only having problems with a conflict in the last 3 rules. The final rule writes the URL I want, but returns travel.php instead of travel2.php

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^journal/([^/]*)$ /journal2.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^travel/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ travel.php?country=$1&url_string=$2
RewriteRule ^travel/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ /travel2.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^travel/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ travel2.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

This is what I'm after from those last 3:

`/travel/country/title-url-string` (currently works & displays correct content)

`/travel/category` (currently works & displays correct content)

`/travel/category/subcat` (currently displays URL as I want it, but returns travel.php content instead of travel2.php)

I originally had an ID number in the travel.php rule, and removing that has resulted in the conflict. I'm aware two of the rules have the same pattern, so how can I best go about getting the results I want? Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: If $_GET["relevant string"] exists is what I was thinking of trying first. I'm a PHP/mod_rewrite novice - there must be a way to get URLs in a consistent folder structure when the page content type varies, as plenty of websites do it. I'm all ears (or eyes) if there's a better way!

Comment: I thought of another idea to avoid a prefix/suffix. My two different tables have fields unique to them, so I can use PHP to check if a field exists. Then the page displays the content relevant to whether the field exists or not in the table I check.

Comment: True, but just checking whether a field name exists can't be as bad as cycling through potentially 50+ records.

Comment: Right but doing it purely from `mod_rewrite` is anytime better than doing it via `php + database query`

Comment: Is it possible to add a unique string to differentiate the patterns that appears in every record from that field, but remove that unique string with mod_rewrite? For example, if every title-url-string ended in xxx, like
'title-url-string=example-xxx'

Comment: But I thought that would appear in the final URL? Your comments above have disappeared. As in PSJ's example below, I don't want anything extra, like "country-" or "category-" appearing in the rewritten URL.

Comment: I don't want the URL in the browser to have a prefix or suffix - I want those to be the URLs I specified in the original question. Isn't it possible?

Comment: It was quite simple in the end. There are currently only 4 categories (and there won't ever be many more), so I moved the 3rd rule to the top and used the or condition for their names:
'RewriteRule ^travel/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ travel2.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2'

Comment: Yes that should work, putting a known URL first is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

From last 3 rewrite rules:

1 & 3 check the same pattern where first one always take effect.

Further, as your category and country values cannot be distinguished each other here, I would suggest to append a unique identifier to the url as below:

```
RewriteRule ^travel/country-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ travel.php?country=$1&url_string=$2
RewriteRule ^travel/category-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ travel2.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

So your matching urls would be:

```
/travel/country-countryname/title-url-string
/travel/category-categoryname/subcat
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of that. I've added to my question to clarify I'm looking for a way around it,

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that sort of thing completely - it's why I took the ID out.